# Загрузка картинок из базы данных в ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

Не удаётся вывести изображение из базы данных. Пытаюсь просто вывести изображения, но получаю это:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Использовал два способа.

Способ 1.

Представление

```
@model IEnumerable<WebApplication1.Models.Clothe>
@{
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
 
<html>
<head>
    <title>Shop</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="row">
        @foreach(var clothe in Model)
        {
            <img src="data:image/png;base64, @Convert.ToBase64String(clothe.Image)"/>
        }
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Модель

```
public class Clothe
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string ClothingName { get; set; }
        public decimal Price { get; set; }
        public byte[]? Image { get; set; }
        public string? ImageMimeType { get; set; }
    }
```

В итоге получаю это:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Способ 2.

Представление

```
@model IEnumerable<WebApplication1.Models.Clothe>
@{
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
 
<html>
<head>
    <title>Shop</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="row">
        @foreach(var clothe in Model)
        {
            <img src="@Url.Action("GetImage", new {clothe.Id})"/>
        }
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Модель такая же.

Метод в контроллере.

```
public IActionResult GetImage(int Id)
        {
            ClotheRepo clotheRepo = new ClotheRepo();
            byte[] image = clotheRepo.GetClotheById(Id, Context).Image;

            if (image != null)
            {
                return File(image, "image/png");
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
```

Итог:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вспомнил про свой топик спустя несколько месяцев. Проблема была в том, что я неправильно загружал изображения в базу данных. Нашёл код в интернете, который написал какой-то индус - проблема решена